# What is android.process.acore?

Tags: system, system-apps, processes

What is the purpose of `android.process.acore`?

I see many, many questions about acore-related error messages and how to fix them, but not really anything about what the process is in the first place. All I was able to find is [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2121899) at xda-developers which suggests it has something to do with Contacts storage. Can anyone provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: [`android.process.acore`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/ContactsProvider/+/android-5.1.1_r29/AndroidManifest.xml#22) seems to be a process specifically defined for an activity of ContactsProvider/ContactsStorage app. See what is  [`android:process`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#proc) and the answers for [Usage of android:process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7142921). Overall, it's a process name defined by an app for its component. That's all I needed to know.

Comment: For me it belonged to `/system/app/ContactsProvider.apk`