# Xiaomi Redmi 4 Malfunctioning

Tags: xiaomi, miui

I have been using my Xiaomi Redmi 4(running on miui global 11.0.2, android 7.1.2) for almost 2 years now and never have I experienced such strange issues. Here's a list of some:

1)Play store: Cannot download any apps from play store. It says the app could not be downloaded, please troubleshoot. So I read the solutions, cleared cache and data from play store. I even uninstalled updates. When I tried to download or update any app, firstly the download did not start(it said downloading and never downloaded anything). Then I closed the app, cleared cache and data and opened it again(keep in mind this is the old version of play store as I uninstalled updates). This time the download started, but it reached around 13.60 mb/30mb and stopped. Then it said downloading again and restarted the download from 0 mb, reached 14.74 mb and stopped again. It kept looping like this 3 or 4 times and then I closed the app. I tried again, this time it download the whole 30 mb but gave me the error -506.

2. Chrome: I figured if I could not download apps from play store I would just download the APKs from chrome, but this didn't work either. When I clicked the download button chrome said "1 download pending" and waiting for network when I had a full strength connection. I tried again, cleared app cache and data, restarted the phone but again it showed download pending(I assure you it is not a connection problem). However browsing on the chrome app is completely fine, its just that I cannot download any files.
3. YouTube(app) keeps signing me out for no reason. It gives me an error and tells me to remove my account and sign in again. I go to settings and try to remove my Google account the remove account button is broken. I have tried to open the app again after rebooting,   but instead of giving me the error the app crashes and it says YouTube has Stopped(and keeps stopping). I have cleared cache, cleared data and rebooted but none of that works. Whenever I clear data or reboot and try to open the app, it crashed and says the app has stopped. I have tried to update the app but I cant- both my play store and chrome are broken.
4. When I reboot the phone the system tells me "android.acore.process" has stopped. I looked up this error on the internet, it said to clear the contacts data and cache. Did it. But this didnt fix the first 3 problems. I have no clue what acore process does.
5. I tried to play the "among us" video game(i had installed it before all these bugs started coming up) but whenever I open the game it says "insufficient space to download resources". I have tons of space left and this has never happened earlier.
6. WiFi not working: I click the WiFi button by scrolling the menu from the top of the screen but it doesn't turn on. I go to the WiFi settings and it says "turning WiFi on" but it never turns on. I rebooted my phone and by luck, somehow, the WiFi turned on and I haven't dared to turn it off since.

7)Settings search has stopped: I've been getting this error for quite some months now, and I don't think this is what's causing all the above problems. But I could be wrong, I have no idea

8. Never before seen strange system issues: I had a game APK saved from before. I tried to install it, it said "problem parsing the package"(I had installed the game from this same APK earlier) . Then I cleared the cache and data of package installer and tried installing, this time it said "insufficient storage space available" when I had plenty left. Please, why is every app malfunctioning? These are my storage stats btw: oh never mind, I tried to click a screenshot, it said "could not capture screenshot". Wow. Anyway, I have 2.39 GB free out of 16gb on internal storage and 25 GB free on my SD card.

I also have McAfee Antivirus Plus(the paid version) on my phone. I scanned and found no viruses. I also scanned with the Xiaomi built in security centre and found no issues.

The only real cause I can figure is that I might have deleted some system files. A few days ago I was on the drives app to clear the "other files" which are a huge mess on Xiaomi, and I deleted a couple of them. Is it possible I might have deleted an important file?

However I saw YouTube tutorials before deleting the "other files", they said it is alright to delete the other files as long as they're not named obb or backup files. Or is this a system bug? I have been on the miui 11.0.2 for about an year and I've never seen this happen before.

I've already posted this question on the Xiaomi forums as well but they have no clue what's going on. They told me to factory reset the phone but I don't want to lose my data. They also said that if the system has been corrupted, factory reset will do no good but they told me try it anyway.

Can someone please tell me what the hell is going on? Maybe some computer experts or software developers know which file I might've
deleted by mistake, or is it some other bug. Please help. My phone is a nightmare!

Comment: no, not possible you deleted important files. do a backup of your pictures to PC. try to backup some apps to micloud and google drive. some apps allow adb backup to PC. do factory reset and check if problem persist

Comment: Is there any other way to fix these problems? If I factory reset I am going to lose my MIUI updates as well and go back to miui10. And since redmi 4 updates have been discontinued since last year, my phone's security will be in jeopardy. Is there any particular app or file in MIUI you know which might be malfunctioning?

Comment: you can enable usb-debugging and run *'adb logcat > log.txt'* open log file with Notepad++ and search for nearby lines mentioning *android.acore.process* maybe there is some useful information

Comment: Will solving the android.acore.process issue fix everything? Like I said I looked it up and the android troubleshooting site said clear the data of contacts, will that not solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is android.process.acore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129015/what-is-android-process-acore)

Comment: The android.acore.process seems to be working fine I guess, haven't seen any more popup system alerts. However this hasn't fixed anything. Downloading is still broken in play store and chrome

Comment: I did what you told but all I saw was lines of code which made no sense to me

Comment: Can you tell me why all my system apps are malfunctioning? The WiFi won't turn on, it doesn't let me capture screenshots, it says insufficient space when I have plenty left, package installer stops working, and all these Google apps are also bugged

Comment: maybe someone can tell you if you show us *"lines of code which made no sense"*. the `>` operator is for redirecting terminal output to some file. once you have it you can share log.txt via pastebin.com (make it valid for 1 week autodeletion because may contain sensitive data like serialno, mac address etc)

Comment: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.9.5